# SCSS Style only the parent div and not its child div

Tags: css

```
<div class="fruits">

  <div class="apple">
     <div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="orange">
     <div></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now how do I style it that apple and orange will have will have a green background and not its child div.

And also by calling `fruit div` and not by `apple` or `orange`

Something like this

```
.fruit {

  div{
   background-color: green;
   }

 }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator, https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#using-the-with-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [child combinator in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator). Or you give your apple/orange divs another class like `fruit`.

```css
.fruits>div {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="fruits">
  <div class="apple">
    apple
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="orange">
    orange
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```